# Can a class name be used as a namespace?

Tags: c++, class, scope, namespaces, header-files

I remember being told that C++ classes have their own namespaces, and that the class name could be used as a namespace for scope resolution, like this:

```
// Example.h
class Example {
    void Private();
public:
    void Public();
}
```

and, later in a manner similar to this:

```
// Example.cpp
#include "Example.h"
using /*namespace*/ Example;
void Private() {}
void Public() {}
```

instead of:

```
// Example.cpp
#include "Example.h"
void Example::Private() {}
void Example::Public() {}
```

but I couldn't find neither an explanation nor an example of that in my books. A brief Google search was also a dead-end. **Is this a real thing?**

Comment: Related QA giving alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553964/using-declaration-cannot-refer-to-class-member

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, namespaces and classes are different.

However, namespaces and classes both introduce a *scope* which may be referred to using the scope resolution operator `::` .

The `using namespace N;` declaration can only apply to namespaces. It's not possible to do something similar for a class.  You can only do `using Example::x;` for specific names `x` inside `Example` to import them one by one.

When providing the member function body out-of-line, you must write `Example::Private()`, there is no alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Every class has its own namespace that everything part of the class declaration belongs to.

You may employ the using directive as you indicate as explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration).

It should be noted that you **cannot** declare a namespace with the same name as a class as shown here:

```
namespace fubar
{
    class snafu
    {
        ...
    };
}
// Cannot do stuff below (ERROR)
namespace fubar::snafu;
{
    // this is not valid, once a class always a class
    // once a namespace, always a namespace
    // a class makes a namespace also but never JUST a namespace
}
```

Do be careful though.  'Using' too much can play real tricks on you and those who inherit your code.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't understand me, despite the examples. There is not a single example/explanation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) that depicts the usage I mentioned. Feel free to prove me wrong with an example, I'd appreciate it.