# using declaration cannot refer to class member

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-methods

Basically, there is a class `Foo` defined in namespace `np`:

```
//Foo.h
namespace np {

    class Foo {
        public:
          static void static_member();
         ...
        }
...
}
```

I wanted to reference the static member in other sources, say `src.cc`

```
//src.cc
#include "Foo.h"

using np::Foo::static_member;
...
static_member()
...
```

after launching compiler, it complained:

```
 error: using declaration cannot refer to class member
```

However, it worked when I changed the line to `np::Foo::static_member()`. So, what are proper ways to omit the interminable scope prefixes?

Comment: There is no way unless `Foo` is a namespace, not a `class` (or `struct`) type.    The call of the function would also need to be in another function.   `np::Foo::static_member()` can be called unqualified in a member function of `np::Foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what are proper ways to omit the interminable scope prefixes?

There is no way. Outside of class scope, `using` declarations can refer to nested *types* in classes, but not to data members, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration).

The shortest you can get is either

```
using namespace np;
Foo::static_member();
```

or go with a pointer-to-member, which is shorter but also slightly more confusing:

```
auto static_member = &np::Foo::static_member;
static_member();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried `decltype(np::Foo::static_member)* static_member`(which I think is the same as your second workaround), compilation was successful but program crashed at the call of `static_member()`; I am working with Android NDK, and backtrace did not tell anything about this crash : (

Comment: If you go with the `decltype`  version you must make sure the pointer-to-member is initialized. The crash you're seeing is probably that you're trying to call a function through a pointer that doesn't point to some valid location in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but I'd go one of two ways (or maybe three?):

1) if it applies try to move this static method into a namespace - since it's static this may work for you (in cases where you need to pass this thing as some sort of templated class, then this approach will not work).
See other people's opinion on this:

[Namespace + functions versus static methods on a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class)
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134540/are-utility-classes-with-nothing-but-static-members-an-anti-pattern-in-c

```cpp
namespace np
{
  void static_non_member();
} // namespace np

// .. in .cpp, should be fine to do this
{
  using namespace np;
  static_non_member();
}
```

2) using declarations work well with classes so you could at least reduce the amount of writing you have to do:

```cpp
// assume same hpp
// cpp
#include "Foo.h"

using Foo = np::Foo;

Foo::static_member();
```

3) bonus round: store a pointer to that function

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

using FunctionPtrT = std::add_pointer<void()>::type;
FunctionPtrT static_ptr = &Foo::static_member;

// Foo::static_member();
static_ptr(); // name this whatever you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add `using np::Foo::static_member;`

You can use any `static` function if you included `Foo.h` and if the function is `public`

For Example:

```
// Foo.h
namespace np
{
  Class Foo
  {
    public:
      static void PrintHello();
  }
}

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void np::Foo::PrintHello()
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}

// main.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
int Main()
{
  np::Foo::PrintHello();
}
```